# New way of using Blade messing up all my Forms in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I am working on upgrading my Laravel 4.2 app to Laravel 5 and I am finding that I have to replace all of my numerous forms in this format:

```
{{ Form::text('username'); }}
```

With this format:

```
{!! Form::text('username') !!}
```

Is this absolutely necessary?  Is there an easier way to do this than going through every single view in my app?  I am using PHPStorm but I don't think ctrl-shift-r is going to help because although it would work for the opening brackets, I will miss changing the closing brackets (I could search and replace `{{Form` with `{!!Form` but then I'd have nothing for my closing brackets).

It just seems like there should be an easier way, and I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex and Ctrl+Shift+R:

For the opening curly braces:

```
Find: \{\{\s*(?=Form)
Replace with: {!!
```

For the ending:

```
Find: (\{!!\s*.*)\s*\}\}
Replace with: \$1 !!}
```

**Note:** run the opening curly braces find and replace first, and then run the ending. There's probably a way to combine the two regexes, but this should work.

**Edit:** just for fun, this is the regex for doing both the opening and ending in one fell swoop:

```
Find: \{\{(\s*Form::.*\s*)\}\}
Replace with: {!!\$1!!}
```

Comment: I ended up having go use this for the second part (for the ending with the find):  (\{!!.*)\}\}   but thanks for the great help!

Comment: Ah, you're right. The backslashes are unneeded in those places and there was no room for spaces. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Your regex doen't account for multiple curly braces with a Form on the same line. This regex fixes that: \{\{([^{}]*Form::[^{}]*)\}\}